# jsp drop down not working !! please assist

Tags: database, jsp, drop-down-menu, resultset

// resultset,resultset2 are properly defined along with rsmd(ResultSetMetaData object) & DB connection is also properly defined
//tr & table tags....

```
    String td_names[] ={"DVD","BOOKS","NOVELS"};

    resultset=statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable");
    rsmd=resultset.getMetaData();
    for(int j=0;j<td_names.length;j++)
            {
    %>
            <td><%=td_names[j]%></td>
    <%
                resultset2=statement2.executeQuery("SELECT " + rsmd.getColumnName(j) + " FROM mytable");
    %>
            <td>
                <select name='drop_'<%=j%> >
    <%    
                    for(int i=0;resultset2.next();i++)
                    {
    %>
                        <option><%=resultset2.getString(i)%></option>
    <%
                    }
    %>
                </select>
            </td>
    <%
    }
```

.......remaining code

Comment: instead of using for loop use while(rs.next())..!

Comment: only one field of table as a single row is displayed.i.e DVD only...not even it's drop down box is being displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

row != column

Please change from

```
for(
```

to

```
while(
```

and

```
getString(i)
```

to

```
getString(1)
```

Please use JSLT-SQL instead.